I am following a video on setting up Qemu/KVM. Setting up of tuned, I am having a problem with missing parameters. How can I correct these errors?
In setting up Qemu and KVM: I received the following notification. 
I have seen several others with this same problem,
but I have not been able to find a post with a resolution to implement.
$ sudo tuned-adm profile virtual-host
$ tuned-adm active
Current active profile: virtual-host
$ sudo tuned-adm verify Verification failed, current system settings differ from the preset profile.
You can mostly fix this by restarting the Tuned daemon, e.g.: systemctl restart tuned
or
service tuned restart Sometimes (if some plugins like bootloader are used) a reboot may be required.
See tuned log file ('/var/log/tuned/tuned.log') for details.

These had no effect.
I have encountered the following errors: Errors in '/var/log/tuned/tuned.log', :
2024-06-26 10:39:06,158 ERROR tuned.plugins.plugin_sysctl: Failed to read sysctl parameter 'kernel.sched_min_granularity_ns', the parameter does not exist.
2024-06-26 10:39:06,158 ERROR tuned.plugins.plugin_sysctl: sysctl option kernel.sched_min_granularity_ns will not be set, failed to read the original value.
2024-06-26 10:39:06,158 ERROR tuned.plugins.plugin_sysctl: Failed to read sysctl parameter 'kernel.sched_wakeup_granularity_ns', the parameter does not exist.
2024-06-26 10:39:06,158 ERROR tuned.plugins.plugin_sysctl: sysctl option kernel.sched_wakeup_granularity_ns will not be set, failed to read the original value.
2024-06-26 10:39:06,158 ERROR tuned.plugins.plugin_sysctl: Failed to read sysctl parameter 'kernel.sched_migration_cost_ns', the parameter does not exist.
2024-06-26 10:39:06,158 ERROR tuned.plugins.plugin_sysctl: sysctl option kernel.sched_migration_cost_ns will not be set, failed to read the original value.

I have found that the above files were re-located here during one of the past updates:
/sys/kernel/debug/sched/
And I guess sysctl can no longer see them.
System:

Kernel: 5.15.0-113-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 11.4.0 Desktop: Cinnamon 6.0.4.
tk: GTK 3.24.33 wm: muffin vt: 7 dm: LightDM 1.30.0 Distro: Linux Mint 21.3 Virginia base: Ubuntu 22.04 jammy.
Machine:
Type: Desktop System: Gigabyte product: H370 WIFI v: N/A serial:
Mobo: Gigabyte model: H370N WIFI-CF v: x.x serial:
UEFI: American Megatrends v: F11 date: 09/17/2018
CPU:
Info: 6-core model: Intel Core i7-8700 bits: 64 type: MT MCP smt: enabled   arch: Coffee Lake rev: A cache: L1: 384 KiB L2: 1.5 MiB L3: 12 MiB
Speed (MHz): avg: 4429 high: 4499 min/max: 800/4600 cores: 1: 4327 2: 4350 3: 4357 4: 4494 5: 4494 6: 4490 7: 4399 8: 4363 9: 4466 10: 4476 11: 4499 12: 4433 bogomips: 76799
Flags: avx avx2 ht lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx

tuned.log:
2024-06-26 10:39:06,115 WARNING tuned.plugins.plugin_cpu: unable to run x86_energy_perf_policy tool, ignoring CPU energy performance bias, is the tool installed?

2024-06-26 10:39:06,158 ERROR tuned.plugins.plugin_sysctl: Failed to read sysctl parameter 'kernel.sched_min_granularity_ns', the parameter does not exist.
2024-06-26 10:39:06,158 ERROR tuned.plugins.plugin_sysctl: sysctl option kernel.sched_min_granularity_ns will not be set, failed to read the original value.
2024-06-26 10:39:06,158 ERROR tuned.plugins.plugin_sysctl: Failed to read sysctl parameter 'kernel.sched_wakeup_granularity_ns', the parameter does not exist.
2024-06-26 10:39:06,158 ERROR tuned.plugins.plugin_sysctl: sysctl option kernel.sched_wakeup_granularity_ns will not be set, failed to read the original value.
2024-06-26 10:39:06,158 ERROR tuned.plugins.plugin_sysctl: Failed to read sysctl parameter 'kernel.sched_migration_cost_ns', the parameter does not exist.
2024-06-26 10:39:06,158 ERROR tuned.plugins.plugin_sysctl: sysctl option kernel.sched_migration_cost_ns will not be set, failed to read the original value.

2024-06-26 10:39:10,676 ERROR tuned.plugins.plugin_sysctl: Failed to read sysctl parameter 'kernel.sched_min_granularity_ns', the parameter does not exist.
2024-06-26 10:39:10,676 ERROR tuned.plugins.base: verify: failed: 'kernel.sched_min_granularity_ns' = 'None', expected '10000000'.
2024-06-26 10:39:10,676 ERROR tuned.plugins.plugin_sysctl: Failed to read sysctl parameter 'kernel.sched_wakeup_granularity_ns', the parameter does not exist.
2024-06-26 10:39:10,676 ERROR tuned.plugins.base: verify: failed: 'kernel.sched_wakeup_granularity_ns' = 'None', expected '15000000'
2024-06-26 10:39:10,677 INFO tuned.plugins.base: verify: passed: 'vm.dirty_ratio' = '40'
2024-06-26 10:39:10,677 INFO tuned.plugins.base: verify: passed: 'vm.dirty_background_ratio' = '5'
2024-06-26 10:39:10,677 INFO tuned.plugins.base: verify: passed: 'vm.swappiness' = '10'.
2024-06-26 10:39:10,677 ERROR tuned.plugins.plugin_sysctl: Failed to read sysctl parameter 'kernel.sched_migration_cost_ns', the parameter does not exist.
2024-06-26 10:39:10,677 ERROR tuned.plugins.base: verify: failed: 'kernel.sched_migration_cost_ns' = 'None', expected '5000000'.


(1) This is hard to understand.  Please [edit] it and try to make it clearer.  (2) While it is useful to present error messages, you need more plain, English, narrative text.  What are you trying to do?  What did you do?  (3) What files were relocated where?  How did you “find” this?  (4) It might help to link to the video you are following.  (5) Why did you tag the question “environment-variables”?

what version of tuned have you installed? I ask, because this was addressed in tuned-2.19.0 almost 2 years ago
